# Checking if the toggle is on or off

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm not positive about the code that I provided below. However, I'm trying to make the bot check whether it's enabled or disabled. So basically, if a mod executed the command `<antilink on>` and executed the command again, I want the bot to return `The anti-link is already on`. The same thing with `off`.

```
if (args[0] === "on") {
  message.channel.send("Anti-link has been turned on.")
  db.set("al_" + message.guild.id, true)
} else if (args[0] === "on") {
  return message.channel.send("Anti-invite is already on.")
}

if (args[0] === "off") {
  message.channel.send("Anti-link has been turned off.")
  db.set("al_" + message.guild.id, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set the value in the db?

I would think you need to get the current value of anti-link which you have stored in the db, and compare it against args[0] to determine whether anti-link is already on or not.